# Double row.names - Point Forecast

Tags: r, statistics

I would like to make a point forecast for an `auto.arima` model:

```
> dput(tsOenb)
structure(c(1.0227039, -5.0683144, 0.6657713, 3.3161374, -2.1586704, 
-0.7833623, -0.2203209, 2.416144, -1.7625406, -0.1565037, -7.9803936, 
9.4594715, -4.8104584, 8.4827107, -6.1895262, 1.4288595, 1.4896459, 
-0.4198522, -5.1583964, 5.2502294, 1.0567102, -1.0923342, -1.5852298, 
0.6061936, -0.3752335, 2.5008664, -1.3999729, 2.2802166, -2.1468756, 
-1.4890328, -0.79254376, 3.21804705, -0.94407886, -0.27802316, 
-0.20753079, -1.12610048, 2.0883735, -0.7424854, 0.44203729, 
-1.48905938, 1.39644424, -3.8917377, 11.25665848, -9.22884035, 
3.26856762, -0.00179541, -2.39664325, 4.00455574, -5.60891295, 
4.6556348, -4.40536951, 6.64234497, -7.34787319, 7.56303006, 
-8.23083674, 4.43247855, 1.31090412, 1.0227039, -5.0683144), .Tsp = c(2000.25, 
2014.75, 4), class = "ts")
> 
> fit <- auto.arima(tsOenb) 
> accuracy(fit)
                 ME RMSE  MAE   MPE MAPE  MASE    ACF1
Training set 0.0707 2.31 1.74 -3468 3627 0.468 0.00353
> 
> vals.arima <- forecast(fit, h=20)
> (vals.arima)
Error in data.frame(`Point Forecast` = c(" 3.0042", "-1.1301", " 1.5542",  : 
  double row.names: 2016 Q3, 2018 Q3
```

As you can see it appears that there are double row names for the forecast. However, I do not get, *WHY* this is an actual error?

Any suggestions, what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your repclies!

Comment: I was able to run your code without an error using forecast version 6.1.  Which version are you using?

Comment: @SamThomas I updated everything and now it also works!